# Is it possible to save layout_weight in an xml?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I need to change the layout_weight of 3 views in a layout, according to the physical size of the screen. The views have the weight of 0-1-0, but this has to change to 0.2-0.6-0.2 when the layout is used in an xlarge screen.

I tried saving the layout_weight inside different copies of the dimensions.xml (one in values/dimensions and an other one in values-xlarge/dimensions), but it looks like I cannot give a dimension without setting dp/px or w/e (cannot save a "raw" number like 1, or 0.2).

Is it possible to do via xml somehow, or do I *have* to work programmatically in order to achieve that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try an integer resource file. It is very similar to dimensions.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html

Comment: You sir, are a life saver! Kudos!

Answer (score 5):

Create a file in your corresponding `values` folders i.e. `values, values-large, values-xlarge, ...`. Add a resources file with content similar to this example:

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item type="integer" name="layout_weight_xy">7</item>
</resources>
```

and then call

```
android:layout_weight="@integer/layout_weight_xy"
```

in your layout file.

Answer (score 2):

You can create special layout in `layout-xlarge` folder and provide different weights there

Comment: I could, but it is much easier to maintain 1 layout, instead of 3 (one for each screen size I want to change the weight of)

Answer (score 2):

First, define your resource e.g integer.xml and make sure you set the correct **type** and **format**. If you want to use it for `layout_weight` you can set `type="integer" format="float"`.

```
<item name="my_weight_value" type="integer" format="float">1.2</item>
```

Then we can use it in layout

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="@integer/my_weight_value"
        android:orientation="vertical">
 </LinearLayout>
```